# C# record type not supported?

Tags: c#, csvhelper, c#-9.0

With a C# `record` defined as

```
public record Traffic(TrafficType Type, string Wan, string Lan, string Domain, string Org, IPAddress SrcIp, string SrcMac, IPAddress DestIp,
        string Protocol, string Scheme);
```

When I attempt to write a collection of them via

```
var all = new List<Traffic>();
// ...populate all
using var writer = new StreamWriter("file.csv");
using var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
csv.WriteRecords(all);
```

I get an exception with the following message:

> An unexpected error occurred.
> IWriter state:
> Row: 1    Index: 0
> HeaderRecord:
> 1

If I convert the collection of record objects to a collection of class objects, then it succeeds. (trying to pass a `record` instance in to a `class` constructor didn't work. I had to create a `class` constructor that took every property of interest from the `record` instance as an explicit argument)

This is a .NET Core 5.0 project using CsvHelper 27.2.1.

Am I correct in concluding that the C# `record` type is not supported by CsvHelper?

Thank you.

Comment: Records are immutable and I'd bet good money that CsvHelper is using some form of reflection to update the object properties, which is why you are seeing a runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with `record`. The issue is the `AutoMap` of `IPAddress`.  If you create a class with properties of `IPAddress`, you will get the same error.  I'm not sure why `AutoMap` throws an exception, it works fine if you manually map all of the properties.  The inner exception of the error is `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var all = new List<Traffic>()
    {
        new (TrafficType.Type1, "Wan1","Lan1","Domain1","Org1",IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), "SrcMac1",IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), "Protocol1", "Scheme1")
    };

    using var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<TrafficMap>();
          
    csv.WriteRecords(all);
}

public class TrafficMap : ClassMap<Traffic>
{
    public TrafficMap()
    {
        //AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // This will throw an exception.
        Map(x => x.Type);
        Map(x => x.Wan);
        Map(x => x.Lan);
        Map(x => x.Domain);
        Map(x => x.Org);
        Map(x => x.SrcIp);
        Map(x => x.SrcMac);
        Map(x => x.DestIp);
        Map(x => x.Protocol);
        Map(x => x.Scheme);
    }
}

public record Traffic(TrafficType Type, string Wan, string Lan, string Domain, string Org, IPAddress SrcIp, string SrcMac, IPAddress DestIp,
        string Protocol, string Scheme);
    
public enum TrafficType
{
    Type1,
    Type2
}
```